# What are the relative internal noise levels in various aircraft?

Tags: airliner, jet, noise, noise-reduction

What are the relative noise levels in various aviation scenarios for observers seated inside an aircraft? I'm sure the specifics depend on model but I'm curious if any general trends can be drawn that are model agnostic.

e.g. Let's consider the following cases for a start:

1. Jet aircraft e.g. 747
2. Jet aircraft gliding with all engines out
3. Helicopter
4. Glider
5. Jet aircraft with noise insulation removed
6. Piston driven prop. aircraft

We could rate on an arbitrary 1 to 100 (noisiest) scale. Even better, in case data is available, I'd love to see the dB values. (@vortaq7's comment below)

I suppose speed will matter so we can probably use their typical cruise conditions for each case?

One motivation is to tease apart contributions from engine vs aerodynamic noise. Another is to quantify the effectiveness of sound insulation.

I suppose most of us never get a chance to really hear an all engines out jet nor to fly in a jet with no sound proofing.

PS. This question was motivated by some comments here:

[What are these green "bags" on the SSJ100?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25133/what-are-these-green-bags-on-the-ssj100/25134?noredirect=1#comment59195_25134)

Comment: If reliable sources could be found it would probably be best to rate the aircraft on a standard scale (Sound Pressure Level (SPL) in dB). This will make it easier to compare to other sound measurements people may come across.

Comment: @voretaq7. Indeed. Great idea. I will change the question to reflect that.

Comment: "*Jet aircraft gliding with all engines out*" would probably be the most noisy cabin. More seriously, it'll depend on the seat location too.

Comment: @mins Noises of human origin? Let's exclude those. :)

Comment: @mins OTOH, I wonder if the gliding would be easy to notice for PAX not paying attention.

Comment: Agreed, but at some point you understand that you are descending, whereas you should be cruising. See also AC 143 and Speedbird 9.

Comment: Entirely subjectively speaking, as someone who's been in 1, 3, 4, and 6 in your above list, I'd rank them glider < modern commercial aviation jet < your typical GA prop aircraft < helicopter. Helos are bloody loud, really quite uncomfortably so. It's hard to have a conversation in a prop plane, or a helo, without amplification. You can practically whisper in a fibreglass 2-seater glider and be heard by the other pilot.

Comment: @Landak I'd agree with your assessment minus the helo part (never been in one unfortunately).  I feel like I should note that different models of glider (and even different gliders of the same model) can have quite different sound characteristics (a Blanik L-23 is much louder than a Grob 103, and they both get significantly louder the faster you fly).

On the same note, the sound levels in commercial jets can vary between models, and even where you sit in the cabin.

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the items for which hard data is easily available: 
[image: Sound levels]

This FAA chart gives relatively average noise levels for passenger jets, GA turbine aircraft, and helicopters. In addition, this chart should start to give an idea of how much noise is generated aerodynamically in aircraft: 
[image: Sound levels aero]

While this is older ground data and not cabin data, it still serves to show that the contribution of aerodynamic noise to total nose levels is not insignificant.

Based on this, I would say that a likely ranking of these environments, from loudest to quietest, is:

1/2: Helicopters and uninsulated jets. In both cases, the close proximity to large, powerful engines leads to extremely high noise levels.

3: General Aviation piston-engined planes. Again, these generally have little insulation,but smaller engines generating somewhat less sound.

4: Passenger jet cabin. Protective insulation reduces sound, but actual noise levels vary based on seat position.

5: Passenger jet cabin, gliding. As seen in the second chart, aerodynamic noise still contributes to a relatively loud environment.

6: Gliders. Slower speeds and cleaner aerodynamic profiles reduce aerodynamic noise, leading to a much quieter ride.